# Moving WordPress from subdirectory to new domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress site stored and served from in a subdirectory: eg https://example.com/en/

We now need to serve it from the root of a new domain eg https://exampletwo.com/, ideally without moving the installation.  The domain is already setup as a parked domain on the cpanel and serves the WordPress site correctly.

Changing the siteurl and homeurl automatically redirects https://example.com/en/ to the new location https://exampletwo.com to the correct location and works fine as expected.

The problem is with external links:
https://example.com/en/ now returns a WordPress 404 error. Setting up a page called /en/ putting a redirect to https://exampletwo.com/ works fine.  A bit clumsy but works for now.

However they also used to have pages like
https://example.com/en/contact and these return server 404 errors outside of WordPress, i.e.:

```
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
```

I'm trying to avoid physically moving the WordPress installation. I'm guessing that when making a request to the /en/ directory, it's actually looking for resources in the /en/en/ directory.

Is it possible to accomplish this using .htaccess / WordPress or some other method or am I best to move the installation to a new location

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the .htaccess code you'd need in the example.com/en/ folder to redirect everything to the exampletwo.com domain. Again, it would go in the /en/ folder and not the root folder for example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampletwo.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```